# Video Quality Measurement test tool

Tags: video, video-quality, streaming, codec, performance

I need to measure streaming video from various different codecs and be able to tell which one is better.

What will be the best metrics to look for?

Is there a free tool that can help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of comparison algorithms available beginning with [PSNR](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-netvc-testing-06.html) through [SSIM/SSIMPLUS](https://www.ssimwave.com/technology/) to [VMAF](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/toward-a-practical-perceptual-video-quality-metric-653f208b9652). VMAF is implemented as an ffmpeg [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf).

Comment: Thanks Michael, kindly can you please also suggest a free tool that can help in the process. Thank you

Comment: @user75464, what do you mean "help in the process?" I'd already suggested ffmpeg as it is able to run the VMAF algorithm. Are you looking to do something else?